# popup field in custom editor resets on play

Tags: unity-game-engine

Trying to code for a custom editor but the dropdown or popup field value always resets when I press play button.

I browsed some similar questions and found solutions in adding apply modified and set dirty but both did not solve the issue.

Any idea what could be happening ?

Here is the code below:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(EnemyAI))]
public class Level_SelectionEditor : Editor
{
    string[] _choices = new[] { "snailer", "sheller" };
    int _choiceIndex = 0;

    override public void OnInspectorGUI()
    {



        // Draw the default inspector
        var mc = target as EnemyAI;



        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("damage"), true);
       EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("attackCounter"), true);

        EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel("Type");
        EditorGUI.indentLevel++;
        _choiceIndex = EditorGUILayout.Popup(_choiceIndex, _choices);



        //updated in code
        if (_choices[_choiceIndex] == "snailer")
        {
            mc.type = EnemyAI.Type.snailer;

            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("snailerEffect"), true);
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("snailerShootPoint"), true);
        }
        else
        {
            mc.type = EnemyAI.Type.sheller;
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("rotationsPerMinute"), true);
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("rotationTime"), true);
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("pauseTime"), true);
        }



        // Save the changes back to the object
        EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the choiceIndex property and base value in the EnemyAI class, and then set it in the EditorScript like this:

```
mc.choiceIndex = EditorGUILayout.Popup(mc.choiceIndex, _choices);
```

Also in the if statement:

```
 if (_choices[mc.choiceIndex] == "snailer"){
     ...
 }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Don't combine

```c#
EditorUtility.SetDirty(target); 
serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
```

Try to never mix `SerialzedProperties` and I call it "direct" properties (using `target`)! This can lead to a lot of troubles.

You are also calling

```c#
serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
```

but I don't see where you call

```c#
serializedObject.Update();
```

to actually get current values first.

Also I guess that comment doesn't belong there

```c#
// Draw the default inspector
var mc = target as EnemyAI;
```

at least it's not what happens there.

---

Finally the reason for your value to get reset is that you introduce `_choiceIndex` in the Editor script so neither `serialzedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties()` nor `EditorUtility.SetDirty(target)` 
will have any effect on it since it is not a SerializedField of the target class. That's not good for another three reasons:

1. the editor script will not be compiled into a build -> that value will not be available
2. you don't have any access to that value also not from your actual class -> what is it good for than?
3. even if it is only a control value for stuff inside the editor: that value will be reset everytime the editor script is initialized. That happens

   - after every recompile
   - after entering or exiting playmode
   - every time the according object gains focus

For saving that value you should put the `_choiceIndex` in the EnemyAI class but why not simply using your enum `EnemyAI.Type` or better said the already existing field `type` instead? Assuming

```c#
[SerialzeField] private EnemyAI.Type type;
```

in your editor script you can simply do

```c#
// This automatically also uses the label "Type"
EditorGuyLayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("type"));
```

and also

```c#
if ((EnemyAI.Type)_choiceIndex.intValue == EnemyAI.Type.snailer)
```

---

Alternatively if you rather want to stick to the string list e.g. for filling more choice options via editor script you could do the same thing with an int instead but also using a `SerializedProperty`.

In EnemyAI

```c#
[SerializeField] private int _choiceIndex;
```

And in the editor

```c#
SerializedProperty _choiceIndex = serialzedObject.FindProperty("_choiceIndex");
_choiceIndex.intValue = EditorGuyLayout.Popup("Type", _choiceIndex.intValue, choices);
```

---

So some of my take away rules are like

1. allways if you want to change/save values use `SerlialzedProperty`. It is sometimes a bit tricky to get them to run (especially e.g. with lists or nested classes) and you can easy make mistakes since you get them by variable name (string). But they bring a lot of benefits like automatically marking stuff dirty, undo/redo etc.
2. the **only** reason to ever use `target as <some type>` to access stuff directly should be to call a method of the class from within the editor (preferred one that doesn't change any of the serialzed values). But also here: Use this only if really necessary because as already mentioned mixing SerializedProperty and direct changes often messes things up.
3. variables should only be introduced within the inspector if

   - you have no interest in saving them
   - they **shall** be reset everytime the Inspector looses focus
   - they are constant values you never change anyway (e.g. labels for fields or your `choices` array)

---

and a last general tip:

you should use `serializedObject.FindProperty` not in every draw call. rather collect all your properties once in `OnEnable()` like

```c#
SerializedProperty _type;
// ...

private void OnEnable()
{
    _type = serializedObject.FindProperty("type");
    // ...
}

public override void OnInpectorGUI()
{
    // ...
    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_type);
    // ...
}
```